# Save stopwatch time to textfile

Tags: c#

I'm creating a memory game (matching game) and I'm trying to save the time the player gets when he/she has matched all the tiles. My streamwriter does work, and I'm curios why. Here's my code for the save method and the method that find if all tiles are matched:

```
    private void Save(string time)
    {
        StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        write.WriteLine(time);
        write.Close();
    }

private void CheckForWinner()
        {
            foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                Label iconLabel = control as Label;
                {
                    if(iconLabel != null)
                    {
                        if (iconLabel.ForeColor == iconLabel.BackColor)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            MessageBox.Show("You finished the game, your time was: " + timeLabel.Text);
            Save();
            //Close(); is outcommented because I want to see if it works.
        }
```

Comment: In your code it seems that you do not call the function `Save`. Do you get any error message or do you simply not get any output to your file?

Comment: Sorry I missed that codesnip, I do call Save but it says: No overload for method Save. I'm new to programming so I'm probably missing something out.

Comment: Unless it is absolutely massive, post your entire code and it is easier to spot where things could be wrong.

Comment: You need to pass the Time string parameter to the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be specifying the parameter `time` when calling `Save`.
Add the `timeLabel.Text` to your function call.

EDIT: A good practice for using `StreamWriter`s is to make use of the `using` command that is available. Since `StreamWriter` is Disposable you can wrap the usage of it inside a `using` and not have to worry about closing it. See the updated Save function.

```
private void Save(string time)
    {
        using(StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(path, true)){
            write.WriteLine(time);
        }
    }

private void CheckForWinner()
        {
            foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                Label iconLabel = control as Label;
                {
                    if(iconLabel != null)
                    {
                        if (iconLabel.ForeColor == iconLabel.BackColor)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            MessageBox.Show("You finished the game, your time was: " + timeLabel.Text);
            Save(timeLabel.Text);
            //Close(); is outcommented because I want to see if it works.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Save should looks like:

```
private void Save(string time)
{
   File.WriteAllText(path, time); // Or AppendAllText, depends on what you want.
}
```

And inside CheckForWinner you have to call not Save() but Save(timeLabel.Text).

Comment: Why not use a StreamWriter?

Comment: Because MS implemented StreamWriter inside these methods, so if you don't need more control over writing (what give you streamwriter) and I guess that guy above don't need, then why don't use shorter variant?

Comment: Edit something so I could undo my downvote. Add some more detail or formatting etc.